# AFNetworking combine data and image to send to PHP

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am (finally) using afnetworking for my iOS project. I have managed with success to send `POST` data and an image to my php server, but in separated blocks of code.

**Send Data:**

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myname,@"name", mysencondname, @"twoname", nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://DOMAIN.COM"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
[httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

[httpClient postPath:@"post.php" parameters:parameters
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
                        NSLog(@"operation hasAcceptableStatusCode: %d", [operation.response statusCode]);
                        [self requestDone:[operation.response statusCode]];
                     }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                        NSLog(@"Error with request");
                        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
                        [self requestFailed];
}];
```

**Send Image:**

```
NSData *imageToUpload = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageView.image);
AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.DOMAIN.com"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"upload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"avatar" fileName:fullFilename mimeType:@"image/png"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *response = [operation responseString];
    NSLog(@"response: [%@]",response);
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if([operation.response statusCode] == 403){
        NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);

}];
```

My question is how can I combine them so I can send an image and some data like (`myname, @"name", mysencondname, @"twoname"`) to my server with a single request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the *multipartFormRequestWithMethod* method there is parameter called *parameters* that you can use to send some data along.

For example:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            myName, @"name"
                            , secondName, @"twoname"
                            , nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"upload.php" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"avatar" fileName:fullFilename mimeType:@"image/png"];
}];
```

Comment: I'll try that one and let you know.Thanks!